# Дефис или отдельно?

Tags: раздельно-дефис, дефис

Сказочно-эльфийский или сказочно эльфийский?

Comment: Контекст или фрагмент нужен, Руслан.

Comment: Ответ исправлен - изменён результат. Новое - после блока с правилом.

Answer (score 4):

Сказочно эльфийский = эльфийский по-сказочному. || Не подходит. Да и эльфийский всегда соотносится со сказкой (то есть эльфийский не может быть не по-сказочному).
*Сказочно богатый = по-сказочному богат; сказочно красивый = по-сказочному красив.*
В раздельных примерах к причастию можно **задать вопрос** *насколько? как?* и слова можно **поменять местами**: *выраженный отчётливо, скрываемый плохо*. Но не *эльфийский сказочно*, и вопрос тоже не подходит.
К тому же, выражается единое понятие - не стоит писать отдельно.
Сказочно-эльфийский = сказочный и эльфийский. || Не совсем подходит, так как определения не однородны.
Но:
*гномо-эльфийский*; || Гномы и эльфы - однородность.
*сказочно-легендарный*; || Сказки и легенды - однородность.
*сказочно-мифологический*. || сказки и мифы - однородность.

Пишутся слитно сложные имена прилагательные, образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчинённых одно другому, например:
*железнодорожный (железная дорога), народнохозяйственный (народное хозяйство), естественнонаучный (естественные науки), сложноподчинённое (сложное по способу подчинения), рельсопрокатный (прокатывающий рельсы), общенародный (общий для народа), полезащитный (образующий защиту для полей), металлорежущий (режущий металл)*;
сюда же относятся обозначающие единое понятие образования (в том числе и терминологические) из наречия и прилагательного (или причастия), например:
*малоупотребительный, близлежащий, животрепещущий, глубокоуважаемый, свежеиспеченный, ясновидящий, сильнодействующий, дикорастущий, вечнозелёный, гладкокрашеный*.
[https://therules.ru/?q=дефис](https://therules.ru/?q=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%81)

Анализируя слитно пишущиеся сложные прилагательные, можно выявить одну ключевую особенность: значение таких слов **не является суммой значений двух прилагательных**:
глубокоуважаемый — уважаемый, но не глубокий;
сильнодействующий — действующий, но не сильный;
малоупотребительный — употребительный, но не малый;
круглогодичный — годичный, но не круглый;
узкопрактический — практический, но не узкий;
высокохудожественный — художественный, но не высокий.

Хоть и прилагательные "*сказочный*" и "*эльфийский*" не однородны, но тем не менее *сказочно-эльфийский* = *сказочный* + *эльфийский*. То есть нужно писать через дефис.

В словарях зафиксировано похожее слово - "*сказочно-колдовской*":
https://classes.ru/all-russian/dictionary-ortho-term-80329.htm

Если сказочные эльфы были бы одним из видов эльфов (допустим, есть лесные эльфы, речные и сказочные), то нужно было бы писать вместе.

Comment: «не стоит писать отдельно»

Согласен, но если тавтология является языковой игрой или, например, в прямой речи передаёт характер героя, то тогда нужно будет написать отдельно. Так?

Comment: Нет. Это не позволяет нарушать правило. Это единое понятие, которое отвечает на вопрос "какой?" Если отдельно - то эльфийский *насколько? как?* - сказочно. Это неправильно. || Отдельный пример - *плохо скрываемый, отчётливо выраженный*. Вопрос к причастию вполне естественно звучит. Более того, тогда слова можно поменять местами: *выраженный отчётливо, скрываемый плохо*. Но не *эльфийский сказочно*.

Comment: @NaeelMaqsudov Всё-таки через дефис. Это уже наверняка. Ответ изменён.

Answer (score 1):

Без контекста тут действительно может показаться сложновато. Среди всех правил применения дефиса только одно оказывается наиболее близким: *Дефис может появиться в сочетании двух синонимичных слов*, например, `стоял тихо-смирно`, `это случилось нежданно-негаданно`, `меня снедает грусть-печаль-тоска`, `раздавая тычки-затрещины`. Но наш случай не является таковым. Это не повторение, а два слова из которых первое дополняет и определяет второе.

Попробуем смоделировать контекст:

- Я видел сказочно эльфийский сон.
- Сказочно эльфийский лес преграждал нам путь.

Наверное можно придумать пример, где эти два слова применялись бы как синонимичная пара для усиления, но такой пример наверняка будет неестественным и очень спорным. То есть только наличие дефиса будет указывать на то, что эти два слова являются таковыми.

Ответ: раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

**Сказочный эльфийский сон.** - полагаю, только так. Это еще хоть как-то можно осмыслить.

Предлагаемая же конструкция бессмысленна, как ни пиши. Контекст дело вряд ли прояснит. Про тавтологичность уже сказали. Но, главное, я вообще не вижу причин, зачем облекать первое прилагательное в наречную (ну или "интерфиксную") форму.

Наречие здесь просто по смыслу не проходит. Можно сказать "сказочно богатый" или "сказочно красивый", но в сочетании с безусловно относительным прилагательным "эльфийский" оно просто бессмысленно. Вариант сочетаемости понятий: сказочно-эльфийский (как мясо-молочный, винно-водочный) - от "сказка" и "эльф" -  тоже ничего кроме удивления не вызывает. Избыточность. Да и гораздо проще для понимания тут написать два прилагательных.

Остается (вроде бы?) только вариант сказочноэльфийский, образованный от "сказочный эльф". Крайне сомнительно, что автор предполагает нечто подобное в отношении сна.

Похоже, правда, что с вариантом "эльфийская сказка" семантический проблем было бы меньше. "Сказка про эльфов" - ну чем не сюжет для сна? 
То есть вариант *"эльфийскосказачный сон"* я не могу отвергнуть по тем же мотивам, но он крайне сомнителен грамматически.

Остается предложенный вариант c двумя неоднородными опеделениями.

*Есть, кстати вообще предположение, что два заведомо неоднородных определения вообще не могу слиться ни в "наречную" (сказочно богатый), ни в "интерфиксную" форму (зелено-синий). Только как сочетание (типа чернометаллургический - от черная металлургия). Не могу уверененно сказать. Но если это так, то решение проблема упрощается до нескольких слов.*